# I am trying to create a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

It takes a file of 500 complaints, returns the number of the complaint as the key and a tuple with the make of the car, date of complaint, Crash True or False, City and State as the value.

```
 ex)   mydict("Complaints.txt")[416]
      ('CHRYSLER', datetime.date(1995, 1, 9), False, 'ARCADIA', 'FL')
```

so far I have :

```
 from collections import defaultdict
import datetime

def fieldict(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        x=[line.split('\t')[0].strip() for line in f] #list of complaint numbers
        y= line.split('\t') #list of full complaints
        d={}
        for j in x:
            Y= True
            N= False
            d[j] = tuple(y[2],datetime.date(y[7]), y[6], y[12], y[13])   #dict with number of complaint as key and tuple with index as values
        return d
```

y is the entire complaint broken up into a list with \t characters removed. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also lean on the csv module a bit (untested):

```
import csv

def fieldict(filename):
    fullDict = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for y in reader:
            fullDict[y[0].strip()] = (y[2],datetime.date(y[7]), y[6], y[12], y[13])
    return fullDict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mydict = fieldict("Complaints.txt")
    print mydict[416]
```

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding your correctly, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import datetime

def fieldict(filename):
    returnDict = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            lineList = line.split('\t')
            index = lineList[0].strip()
            complaint = tuple(lineList[2],datetime.date(lineList[7]), lineList[6], lineList[12], lineList[13])

            returnDict[index] = complaint

    return returnDict

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mydict = fieldict("Complaints.txt")
    print mydict[416]
```